# Creating an array from the values of another array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, encoding

New to java and I am working on a [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) encoder. A method I am working on right now requires to convert an array of example:
`{13,13,13,4,4,4,4,4,4}`
to 
`{3,13,6,4}`.
It checks the numbers that appear in consecutive order and then prints that into `index[i]`, then prints the actual number value in `index[i+1]`.

My current issue is that if a number is repeated more than 15 times, I have to start a new "run". So `{13,13,13,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,}` (there are 20 4's in succession here) will print `{3,13,15,4,5,4}`. My code currently prints `{3,15,20,4}`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte [] flatdata = {15,15,15,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};
    int count = 1;


    for (int i = 0; i < flatdata.length - 1; i++) {
        if (flatdata[i] != flatdata[i + 1]) {
            count++; }

    }

    byte numLength = 1;
    byte indexNum = 0;
    int newArraySize = count * 2;

    byte[] newArray = new byte[newArraySize];
    byte[] arrayWithTotalIndexes = new byte[newArraySize];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < flatdata.length - 1; i++) {
        if (flatdata[i] != flatdata[i + 1]) {
            newArray[indexNum] = numLength;
            newArray[indexNum + 1] = flatdata[i];
            indexNum = (byte) (indexNum + 2);
            numLength = 1;
        } else {
            numLength++;
        }
    }
    if (flatdata[i - 1] == flatdata[i]) {
        newArray[indexNum] = numLength;
        newArray[indexNum + 1] = flatdata[i];
    } else {
        newArray[indexNum] = numLength;
        newArray[indexNum + 1] = flatdata[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flatdata));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    System.out.println("countRuns: " + count);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayWithTotalIndexes));
    byte[] desiredArray = {3,15,15,4,5,4};
    System.out.println("Desired Array: " + Arrays.toString(desiredArray));
}
```

I know my first step has to be to adjust the size of the new array to include the extra entries of the array.

```
public static void main(String [] args){

        byte [] arr = {15,15,15,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,};

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count1 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count1 > 15) {

                System.out.println("true");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
```

I thought about running a separate loop to check if a number is repeated more than 15 times to change the size of the new array but it has been to no avail.

Here is a link to a previous question I asked regarding the same method in case it makes things more clear.

[Creating an array from another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582538/creating-an-array-from-another-array)

Would appreciate any tips or ideas on how to tackle this.

Comment: after writing this i thought of using the outputed array [3,15,20,4], to make a another new array that loops through it and if an even index is greater than 15, it adds two more indexes to the new array. This solves my changing of index problem.

Comment: tl;dr code, but this might be enough: change `if (flatdata[i] != flatdata[i + 1])` to `if (flatdata[i] != flatdata[i + 1] || numLength == 15)`

Comment: this did indeed work, now i just need to change the size of the original array to have the extra indexes. THANK YOU! i wish i could highlight your reply as a solution

Comment: Re changing the size of the array, the maximum you'll need is still `count * 2`, because shrinking 15 copies to `[15, n]` for each block of 15 is still takes much less space than `count * 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the test for starting a new result pair by changing:

```
if (flatdata[i] != flatdata[i + 1])
```

to:

```
if (flatdata[i] != flatdata[i + 1] || numLength == 15)
```